# Are vectors only allowed in spaces of equal dimensions?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I often have to draw velocity vectors at the time and I wonder about the following statement, which is unfortunately not written down, but I suggested it:

> Edit: By dimension, I mean physical dimension like length, time,...<

When you have to draw a velocity vector to a curve of a moving object, then the axis have to be of equal dimensions (in this case a place):

[image]

So I could name the axis displacement of x, y,  z or any letter I like, but both have to be a direction. I mustn't draw these velocity vectors in a plane of displacement over time .

Is this correct? Or is it only correct when those vectors have to form a tangential line to the curve ?

I haven't seen a curve/vector composition yet, where displacement and time were used at the same time.

Comment: If you are drawing velocity vectors along a curve, then these vectors are of the same dimension the curve lives in (Curves in 3D space will have 3D tangent vectors), but they only will define a tangent line to the curve. This is because the curve is a 1 Dimensional object and its tangent space must have the same dimension as it.

Surfaces have tangent planes and so on.

Comment: Hi, take a look here http://mathonline.wikidot.com/parameterization-of-curves-in-three-dimensional-space

Answer (score 1):

A crucial point about vectors is that we can treat the various components **separately**.  If we have two vectors,  and , in which the first component is in "miles per hour" and the second component is in "km per min" them adding them just gives  where, again, the first component is in "mph" and the second in "km/min".

It is only when you combine different components, as in calculating the length of a vector that you have to convert the components to the same units.

If you are talking about vectors where the different components are different kinds of thing, say the first component is "speed" and the second "acceleration" then you are sharply restricted in what operations you can use.  In fact, those are so far from what I would call "vector algebra" that I would be inclined to use the word "array" rather than "vector".

Answer (score 1):

Mathematically, for something to be a vector, it has to satisfy the axioms of a vector space: scaling a vector gives a vector, and adding two vectors is also a vector. In this sense, every collection of quantities, even if they have different dimensions, is a vector. For example, $(V,T,t)$ in the sense of voltage, temperature, time, is a vector in a sense, that it can be a column that solves a certain set of linear equations (matrices, operating on a vector space). However, in this elementary notion of a vector space, we did not require a dot product (so lengths, angles and rotations have no meaning).

However, in physics, a notion of vectors (and tensors in general) is more strict: we only call it a vector, if it *transforms* as a vector (that is, when you change coordinates, the relations between the vectors stay the same, and the vectors retain the same meaning). In this sense, something is a vector only if it represents the same abstract notion of direction without regard of coordinates. Vectors are the things you can work with symbolically in coordinate-free way (of course, for calculating something, you may pick a basis and split the vectors into components).

Tangents to curves are proper vectors in this sense: rotating the curve in space rotates the tangent with it, it just expresses differently in different coordinates. If you "squeeze" the space (horizontal units in km and vertical in m), then you distort the phisical angles on a paper, but for the rest of the relations, it still works. It's rare that we'd call it a vector if it's an arrow with axes in different physical quantities. Time and space are actually still ok, when we are dealing with relativity and realize they are actually components of a single space-time vector (with the speed of light acting as conversion of all components into the same units, so they can transform correctly upon change of coordinates).